# Classes and objects in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, refactoring

Is there any problem with using conventional classes and objects in the code while using Angular?

For example, sometimes, when I'm refactoring and I want to separate a specific logic that is mixed up in a messy code I do something like...

logic-handler.ts

```js
export class LogicHandler {
  var1: Obj1;
  var2: Obj2;

  constructor(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
}
```

...and I instantiate an object of this class to handle this certain logic, within the component.ts file.

The problem is that there was a senior on my team who always said he didn't like this idea because he didn't know how **Angular** deals with `new LogicHandler();`.

So, is there a real reason to worry about this?

I hope someone can answer my question or provide a better solution to the problem presented.

The fact is that doing it the way I propose is simpler and easier to test.

Comment: I don't see a reason to worry... the components themselves work the same way.  It's really just typescript at that point until you add a decorator that marks it as an angular-specific class, like "@Component" for components...  classes with constructors are supported in TS: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html  I use them for basic models and sometimes extend them and/or implement interfaces.

Comment: Really if your class has only properties you should use [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) to not overcomplicate the code, but there's not problem to use class

Answer (score 1):

As implied by @browsermator in the question comments, there is absolutely no issue using normal classes for other uses than for Angular components.

Your app code is normal TypeScript (and JavaScript) code, so classes are supported.

What Angular does, during its AOT phase, is to pick-up all classes decorated with `@Component`, wrap them (e.g. to link with template and style), and handle all the instantiation during runtime (`new`...). Same for services and modules.

Therefore, as long as you do not decorate your normal classes with Angular stuff, Angular leaves them alone, and you can use them as in non-Angular world.

BTW there is a high chance you *already* use such normal class instantiation, typically with `new Date()` (even if through libraries like `date-fns` and the like), which proves that there is no compatibility issue with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Researching more on the topic, I was able to see that the only problem with this approach is that I am creating a dependency between my component and the `LogicHandler`.

So, if I need to test my component, for example, I won't be able to mock this object easily, because the dependency is inside the component, and not injected into it. Therefore, it does not respect **SOLID**'s dependency inversion principle (**DIP**).

Therefore, the correct option in this case would be to create the `LogicHandler` as a ***service***, and inject it into my component via the constructor.

> In short, it is a matter of principle to never instantiate an object within another class directly, precisely because an object should never be responsible for its dependencies.